# Laravel and stored procedures SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that client has made.
Now I have to access it and process data in my laravel app.

I have no problems with connecting to SQL but the problems starts when passing in parameters.

Here is my code:

```
$connections = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
    ->select(EXEC [stored].[procedure].[here] $param1, $param2);
```

The error I got back is:
The active result for the query contains no fields

I have searched for many hours in forums and here is what I have found:

```
$connections = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
->select(DB::raw('EXEC [stored].[procedure].[here] $param1, $param2'));
```

Error I got back is:
The active result for the query contains no fields.

I have installed SQL driver and OBDC driver.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Check this link hope it helps [Stored Procedures in Laravel](https://medium.com/@smayzes/stored-procedures-in-laravel-60e7cb255fc9)

Comment: Thanks for the help but in the article I find everything I have already tried.

Comment: Try passing the params as an array [How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel)

Comment: Same thing: Active result for the query contains no fields

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/52070741/4848587?

Comment: ye well it turns out he is passing me results as a xml. Any Idea how to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but [this answer suggests](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-mssql-call-procedures) you put your DB::raw around just the params instead of the `EXEC stored.proc.name`.

So instead of

```
 $connections = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw('EXEC [stored].[procedure].[here] $param1, $param2'));
```

Try

```
 $connections = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('EXEC stored.proc.name' . DB::raw($param1, $param2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but if I do as you suggest then I got back the same message:active result for the query contains no fields

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I found out the issue.

It turns out the client sent me over a variable with xml.
As far as I figured out from Microsoft docs then you can`t pass xml as a varable because if you call the SP from an application it is gonna pass it as an array and application can`t parse xml into array directly. You have to do it on your own.

What can be done instead is to pass xml as a value of an array and then take it from there.