# How to call SQL Server stored procedure in Laravel with out parameter

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is to call a stored procedure in SQL Server - Framework Laravel

I read the following post
[Laravel Model SQL Server: Get Output Parameters from Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070741/laravel-model-sql-server-get-output-parameters-from-stored-procedure)

But that did not work!

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetUsers1 
    @namein VARCHAR(10),
    @idn INT,
    @emailin VARCHAR(50),
    @Xout INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.users 
    WHERE name = @namein 
      AND id = @idn 
      AND email = @emailin

    SELECT @Xout = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

how to get `Xout` Parameter in Laravel or PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $namein = 'namein';       
        $idn = 1;
        $emailin = 'emailin';
        $Xout = 1;        
       
        DB::statement('CALL GetUsers1 (?, ?, ?, ?, @Xout);',
            array(
                $TParCategoriaFk,
                $Exito,
                $ResultadoJson,
                $Mensaje
            )
        );
        $results = DB::select('select @Xout as Xout');
        
        echo($results[0]->Xout);
```